# Ruby: Continue looping through an array of fixed length, adding 1 to each element for each iteration

Tags: arrays, ruby, conditional-statements

```
def baubles_on_tree(ornaments, branches)
  counter = 0
  decorations = []
  
  
  puts ornaments, branches
  # Evenly distribute ornaments across branches
  
  # if there are no branches, return string
  if branches == 0
    return "Grandma, we will have to buy a Christmas tree first!"
  end
  
  puts "The number of ornaments (#{ornaments}) divided by branches (#{branches}) equal " + ((ornaments / branches).to_f).to_s
  
  # add 1 to the decorations array while counter <= ornaments.
  # ensure decoration.length maxes out at branches
  
    while counter <= ornaments

      # Add 1 to counter until it reaches the number of ornaments
      counter += 1
      #puts decorations.length
      
      # Push 1 to the decorations array for each iteration
      decorations << 1
      
      # if the decorations array length equals the number of branches,
      # stop creating new indices and instead add 1 to each array element
      if decorations.length == branches 
        print decorations.length
         
        decorations.map! {|n| n + 1 }
      end
      
    end
    print decorations
  
end

Test.describe("Here are some test cases") do
  Test.assert_equals(baubles_on_tree(5,5),[1,1,1,1,1])
  Test.assert_equals(baubles_on_tree(5,0),"Grandma, we will have to buy a Christmas tree first!")
  Test.assert_equals(baubles_on_tree(6,5),[2,1,1,1,1])
  Test.assert_equals(baubles_on_tree(50,9),[6,6,6,6,6,5,5,5,5])
  Test.assert_equals(baubles_on_tree(0,10),[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
end
```

PROBLEM: Hi, everyone. I'm having difficulty finding the correct syntax to use within the if decorations.length == branches block. At present, the

```
decorations.map! {|n| n + 1 }
```

adds 1 to every element in the decorations array for each iteration. Instead, I would like to add 1 to a single array element (going from left to right) until the counter is equal to the number of ornaments.

OBJECTIVE: The final objective of the baubles_on_tree function is to evenly distribute ornaments across all branches of the Christmas tree. If ornaments = 7 and branches = 5, the array to be returned will be `[2,2,1,1,1]`.

Appreciate your guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach can be vastly simplified.

#### The easy way

```
1 def baubles_on_tree(ornaments, branches)
2   return "Grandma, we will have to buy a Christmas tree first!" if branches.zero?
3   tree = Array.new(branches) { |e| ornaments / branches }
4   (ornaments % branches).times { |i| tree[i] += 1 }
5   tree
6 end
```

You're thinking about this in terms of how you would do it as a human, sticking ornaments on a tree one at a time. And you're using loops and things to emulate that behavior. Sometimes it's important to step back, look at your desired result, and come up with the most efficient way to get that result.

If we do this instead, we can skip a lot of loop logic:

1. Divide `ornaments` by `branches`.
2. Assign that value to each element of an array of size `branches`.
3. Iterate over the remainder of your ornaments, adding one to each branch until we run out.

That reduces the number of iterations (loops) to whatever doesn't divide evenly over the branches.

To implement this, we need two lines of code.

1. On line 3, we create the array in steps 1 and 2 above. `Array.new(branches)` will create an array with the same number of elements as `branches`. The block tells `Array.new` what value to assign to each element. In this case, we assign `ornaments / branches`.
2. On line 4: `ornaments % branches` is the remainder of `ornaments / branches`. So, this line executes the block passed to the `#times` method `ornaments % branches` times, passing `0` through `ornaments % branches - 1` to `i` one after the other. We add `1` to each of the elements at those indexes.

Applying the test `baubles_on_tree(50,9)`:

1. Line 3 creates an array with nine elements. `50 / 9` is `5`, so after that line, `tree == [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]`.
2. Line 4 then adds `1` to the first five elements, because `50 % 9` is `5`, and we get `tree == [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5]`.

On line 5, we return `tree` to the caller, and Bob's your uncle. :)

#### The hard way, with an explanation of where you're going wrong

To answer your specific question: the reason that you are getting a great big array of `1`'s with a few `2`'s at the beginning, instead of the values that you are looking for, is because you are pushing a `1` onto your array once for each ornament, instead of adding `1` to the appropriate array element once for each ornament. That's what `decorations << 1` does. Do that 50 times, you'll get an array with 50 `1`'s in it.

So, you get an array of size `ornaments` with a `1` in each element. And in the one iteration of your loop where your array (`decorations`) is the same size as `branches`, you add `1` to all the values in the array at its current size, and then keep on sticking `1`'s on the end of it until you run out of ornaments.

So you get an array of size `ornaments`, with a `2` in the first `branches` elements, and a `1` in every other element.

To do it right, you have to loop around `ornaments` (you got that right), but inside the ornament loop, you have to loop around `branches` and add `1` to each element (and keep incrementing the outside `ornament` loop counter while you're at it, because you're using up an ornament each time you loop through the inner loop). You also have to figure out how to get started, and how to make sure you stop in time when you run out of ornaments.

Something like this (which passes your tests):

```
def baubles_on_tree(ornaments, branches)
  return "Grandma, we will have to buy a Christmas tree first!" if branches.zero?
  decorations = []

  # First, put the right amount of zeros in the array (ensure that
  # decorations.size == branches, and each element has a 0 in it)
  counter = 0
  while counter < branches
    decorations << 0
    counter += 1
  end

  # Then, loop through ornaments
  counter = 0
  while counter < ornaments

    # Inside the ornaments loop, loop through branches. We have to keep track
    # of the outer loop here, too, because if we run out of ornaments before
    # we're done putting an ornament on each branch, we want to quit right away.
    counter2 = 0
    while counter2 < branches && counter < ornaments

      # ADD 1, don't push 1 (don't use <<)
      decorations[counter2] += 1 

      # increment both counters; since we're putting an ornament on each branch,
      # we have to keep the outer loop going while we loop through the inner one
      counter2 += 1
      counter += 1
    end
  end
  decorations # Return the array
end
```

While that might be an interesting exercise in using nothing but `while` loops, it's a lot easier to just do a little arithmetic and get the same result.

Comment: Excellent comment, Bob, and thank you for your help (again!). I knew there was a much more efficient way to solve this problem, but I wasn't familiar with the "times" method. Thanks again for breaking it down!

Comment: @MrSandman98765 Oh, that's right, you're the "#each` vs. `#map` guy. :) You're very welcome. `#times` is the "Ruby idiomatic" version of the `for` loop. Ruby has a `for` loop, but the standard convention is to use `#times`.

Answer (score 1):

This works.

Note: It seems that your beginner in Ruby, so I tried to do my code as simple as possible :)

```
def create_arrays(nb_element, nb_arrays)
  arrays = []
  i = 0
  loop do
    arrays[i] = Array.new(nb_element)
    i += 1
    if i == nb_arrays
      break       # this will cause execution to exit the loop
    end
  end
  return arrays
end

def get_nb_arrays(ornaments, branches)
  if ornaments == 0
    return branches
  else
    return ornaments/branches + ornaments % branches
  end
end

def baubles_on_tree(ornaments, branches)
  if branches == 0
    return "Grandma, we will have to buy a Christmas tree first!"
  end

  arrays = create_arrays(branches, get_nb_arrays(ornaments, branches))
  n = ornaments

  i = 0
  while i < arrays.length
    ar = arrays[i]

    j = 0
    while j < ar.length
      if n > 0
        ar[j] = 1
      else 
        ar[j] = 0
      end
      n -= 1
      j += 1
    end
    i += 1
  end
  return arrays.transpose.map {|x| x.reduce(:+)}
end
```

Good luck !

Comment: You got it to work, and that's a good thing. But the code can still be done a lot more simply than this, even if you do use `while` loops. :) See my answer.

Comment: Thank you, BinaryMan, for your solution. I know you said you were intentionally making your code verbose to keep things simple, but I actually found it more difficult to follow than Bob's refactored solution above. Still, I found breaking down your code was beneficial, and I appreciate your effort.

Comment: @BinaryMan I think that you might have missed the idea of incrementing `i` inside of the `j` loop, and as a result had to torture your code a bit by keeping track of `n` separately. I can't say it's something I would have thought of if I hadn't been half asleep, and had this vision of an ornament popping out of a box every time the inner loop incremented.